# JSON Parsing help in Python

Tags: python, json

I have below data in `JSON` format, I have started with code below which throws a `KEY ERROR`.

Not sure how to get all data listed in headers section.

I know I am not doing it right in `json_obj['offers'][0]['pkg']['Info']:` but not sure how to do it correctly.

how can I get to different nodes like info,PricingInfo,Flt_Info etc?

```
{  
   "offerInfo":{  
      "siteID":"1",
      "language":"en_US",
      "currency":"USD"
   },
   "offers":{  
      "pkg":[  
         {  
            "offerDateRange":{  
               "StartDate":[  
                  2015,
                  11,
                  8
               ],
               "EndDate":[  
                  2015,
                  11,
                  14
               ]
            },
            "Info":{  
               "Id":"111"
            },
            "PricingInfo":{  
               "BaseRate":1932.6
            },
            "flt_Info":{  
               "Carrier":"AA"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}

import os
import json
import csv


f = open('api.csv','w')
writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter = '~')
headers = ['Id' , 'StartDate', 'EndDate', 'Id', 'BaseRate', 'Carrier']
default = ''
writer.writerow(headers)

string = open('data.json').read().decode('utf-8')
json_obj = json.loads(string)

for pkg in json_obj['offers'][0]['pkg']['Info']:
        row = []
        row.append(json_obj['id']) # just to test,but I need column values listed in header section
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Maybe I am blind but I do not see anywhere the "hotelInfo" key in your json

Comment: My bad,corrected the right key name @Marco,but the problem still persist.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to get ? just the id of each package? or you need other fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to substitute this piece of code:

```
for pkg in json_obj['offers'][0]['pkg']['Info']:
        row = []
        row.append(json_obj['id']) # just to test,but I need column values listed in header section
        writer.writerow(row)
```

With this:

```
for pkg in json_obj['offers']['pkg']:
    row.append(pkg['Info']['Id'])
    year  = pkg['offerDateRange']['StartDate'][0]
    month = pkg['offerDateRange']['StartDate'][1]
    day   = pkg['offerDateRange']['StartDate'][2]
    StartDate = "%d-%d-%d" % (year,month,day)
    print StartDate
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: It worked @Marco.. but why the StartDate comes as [2015,11,8],is there any way I can remove the [] and format to a proper YYYY-MM-DD string?

Comment: I have updated the answer to trasnform the date as you requested.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're accessing the json incorrectly. After you have accessed `json_obj['offers']`, you accessed [0], but there is no array there. `json_obj['offers']` gives you another dictionary.

For example, to get PricingInfo like you asked, access like this:

```
json_obj['offers']['pkg'][0]['PricingInfo']
```

or 11 from the StartDate like this:

```
json_obj['offers']['pkg'][0]['offerDateRange']['StartDate'][1]
```

And I believe you get the KEY ERROR because you access [0] in the dictionary, which since that isn't a key, you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import os
import json
import csv

string = open('data.json').read().decode('utf-8')
json_obj = json.loads(string)


print json_obj["offers"]["pkg"][0]["Info"]["Id"]

print str(json_obj["offers"]["pkg"][0]["offerDateRange"]["StartDate"][0]) +'-'+ str(json_obj["offers"]["pkg"][0]["offerDateRange"]["StartDate"][1])+'-'+str(json_obj["offers"]["pkg"][0]
["offerDateRange"]["StartDate"][2])

print str(json_obj["offers"]["pkg"][0]["offerDateRange"]["EndDate"][0]) +'-'+ str(json_obj["offers"]["pkg"][0]["offerDateRange"]["EndDate"][1])+'-'+str(json_obj["offers"]["pkg"][0]
["offerDateRange"]["EndDate"][2])

print json_obj["offers"]["pkg"][0]["Info"]["Id"]

print json_obj["offers"]["pkg"][0]["PricingInfo"]["BaseRate"]

print json_obj["offers"]["pkg"][0]["flt_Info"]["Carrier"]
```